# How to close a Colorbox from a CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I want to close Colorbox from a controller. I used this code but it will not work:

```
<?= "$(document).ready(function() { $.colorbox.close(); });"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me they are two options:

a)(Easy) inside your controller print js , example: 
    `echo "<script type='text/javascript'> parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); </script>";`

but if you after redirects with redirect("yoursite"); codeigniter will show error , the other option is:

b) you need create in view a simple .php for example close_colorbox.php , inside write this code:
    `if (isset($script)) { echo $script; }`

After in your controller include the next code:

```
$data['script'] = " <script type='text/javascript'> window.top.location.reload(); parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(); </script> ";

$this->load->vars($data);

$this->load->view('close_colorbox');
```

*note: window.top.location.reload(); is optional if you want reload the parent content